# How to use more recent version of Javascript in IntelliJ IDEA plugin Http Client

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, httprequest

I am bothered. I just wrote my own function for encoding JSON to not encrypted JWT, pretty simple but I am not really a Javascript developer. My code use spread operator and btoa(...) function which seems pretty common. And as a standalone Javascript app it worked perfectly.
But.
Now I want to be able to load this as a module in my Http Client requests (IntelliJ plugin), but the Javascript interpreter complains at first on my use of spread-operators, Http Client doesn't know what that is at all, and then when I replaced them with using Object.assign(...) it complains that the btoa() method doesn't exist. The Buffer or Base64 doesn't exist either.

Can anyone here at StackOverflow help me out? Obviously an older Javascript interpreter is used, but how do I change version for my Http Client? I already tries to use NodeJS 20 in Settings for Javascript.